# matplotlib; right allign parts of one string

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a python newbie. 
I created a plot with a text box underneath. The problem I have is the formatting of the Text box. 
I want to have 'Mean:' left aligned where as the value and its unit should be right aligned. Well basically the problem comes with the second line where the value does not line up with the one above. tab-space did not work.
I googled a lot and tried things like .rjust etc., but the problem seems to be that I could not include it into the multiple string form I used.

edited Code!

It produces something like ('_' instead of space:

Mean:____8.60 A

Stdev:_3.01 A

But I need (I could not solve it just with adding spaces)

Mean:___8.60 A

Stdev:___3.01 A

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [4, 7, 9, 10, 13]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y,)

std = format(round(np.std(y), 2), '.2f')
mean = format(round(np.mean(y),2), '.2f')


plt.gcf().text(0.14, 0.07, ('Mean:        '+(str(mean)+' $\\AA$')+'\nStdev:       '+(str(std)+ ' $\\AA$')), fontsize=20, bbox=dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='black', pad=10))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.show()
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. With the information given, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: `Figure.text` takes `horizontalalignment`( and `verticalalignment`) parameters

Comment: @ Piinthesky Thanks for comment, I updated the Code above.

Comment: @ Paul H 
I don't understand what you mean, could you please take the code line and add you suggestion as an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classically, you can solve this kind of problem by [using monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). In these kind of fonts, each glyph (including space) has the same width. You can therefore align things using the appropriate number of spaces.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y,)

plt.gcf().text(0.14, 0.07, "Mean:{:10.2f} $\\AA$\nStdev:{:9.2f} $\\AA$".format(np.mean(y),np.std(y)), fontdict={'fontsize':20, 'family':'monospace'}, bbox=dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='black', pad=10))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.show()
```

You'll notice I've simplified your code to take advantage of [Python's great formatting capabilities](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html). I ask Python to convert the number `np.mean(y)` into a string with 2 significant digits (`{:.2f}`) but in addition, I'm asking the resulting string to be 10 char long (including the dot and the 2 significant digits: `{:10.2f}`). By default, this padding is done with spaces and numbers are right aligned.

It's very powerful because I don't need to know how many digits does my number has to the left of the coma. `"{:10.2f}\n{:10.2f}".format(100,1)` will print

```
____100.00
______1.00
```

automatically (but with spaces instead of _ of course).

See also https://pyformat.info/ for more info.

[image]

If you don't want to use monospaced fonts, things are more complicated. I think your best bet is to use 2 `Text` object, one with the left part of your text, aligned left, and a second one with the numbers, right-aligned.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y,)

fontprops = {'fontsize':20}
boxprops = dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='black', pad=10)
plt.gcf().text(0.14, 0.07, "Mean:\nStdev:", fontdict=fontprops)
plt.gcf().text(0.50, 0.07, "{:.2f} A\n{:.2f} A".format(np.mean(y),np.std(y)), fontdict=fontprops, ha='right')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

There is one complication with your code, in that you're using mathtext to display the Å symbol, which makes the spacing of the lines unequal. So you'd have to play around with the linespacing of the left textbox to get the alignment right. Plus you'd have to draw a `Rectangle` object by hand around your text if you so desire... In the end I'm not sure the effort would be worth the result.

Comment: Thank you very much, I chose the second solution to be independent from fonts. To get back the frame around I added some spaces to the left text box and enabled the box option. Maybe not the nicest way to do, but it gives the result I need.